# How can I add one or increment the integer each time I hit the submit button?

Tags: java, html, jsp

jsp file

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="index.jsp" />

<% 
String integer = request.getParameter("integer"); 
%>

<%
int x = 0;
try { x = Integer.parseInt("integer"); }
catch (Exception e) { x = 0; }
%>

<input type="text" name="integer" value="<%=x%>"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

how would I add or increment x the output each time when I hit the submit button?

Comment: You should not mix backend code and jsp.

Comment: @Alexey, correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't jsp mean Java Server Pages...the server is backend

Comment: You can mix java code and html but it's not good practice. You should do java in servlet/controller etc. and html, jstl in jsp to have a clean code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Integer.parseInt("integer"); -> "integer" string is not a number therefore it will be a wrong format.
```

and you are initializing x = 0 every time and there is no increment on x

you could try this:

```
<form method="post" action="" />

<%
  String integer = request.getParameter("integer");          
  int x = integer != null ? Integer.parseInt(integer) : 0;      
  ++x;
%>

<input type="text" name="integer" value="<%=x%>"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="index.jsp" />

<% 
String integer = request.getParameter("integer"); 
%>

<%
int x = 0;
try { x = Integer.parseInt("integer"); }
catch (Exception e) { x = 0; }
x = x + 1;
%>

<input type="text" name="integer" value="<%=x%>"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```